# Create video file with multiple audio tracks

Tags: video, audio, video-editing

I have an animated movie in three different languages, each in a separate video file. The picture is exactly the same for each file, only the audio is different.

I want to merge all these files into one, so that I have a single video file where I can switch easily between the audio tracks in VLC.
What software can I use to merge the audio tracks into a single file?

I can use any OS for the job, but my preferred order is: OS X, Linux (Debian/Ubuntu/Mint), Android, iOS, Windows desktop. It's not really important, though, I'll take suggestions for any platform happily.

The only function I really need is the merging itself. Lightweight solutions are a a plus.

Answer (score 1):

I very much like to use the windows version of the MkvToolNix Tools you can find at https://mkvtoolnix.download/downloads.html (There are options for a wide variety of OS).

You can add multiple video files as input, and then choose which video track and which audio tracks you want to merge into a new mkv file. You will just have to make sure you identify the correct delays for the corresponding audio tracks in order to sync audio properly.